# asp.net SweetAlert not working

Tags: asp.net, sweetalert

I have a sweetalert problem. I click delete but alert message looking problem

```
function checkDelete() {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function () {
        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
    });
}

<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" OnClientClick="checkDelete();return false;">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

[image]

Comment: What is displayed in your browser's JavaScript console window / web-inspector?

Comment: Had same problem today - had forgotten to include sweetalert css ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSessionExpire(msgtxt) {
        swal({
            title: "",
            text: msgtxt,
            type: "error",
            showCancelButton: false,
            confirmButtonColor: "#008b8b",
            confirmButtonText: "OK",
            cancelButtonText: "",
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            closeOnCancel: true
        },
    function (isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            //swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
            setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = 'frmLogin.aspx' }, 1);
        } else {
            //swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
            setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = 'frmLogin.aspx' }, 1);
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use another method.
first create a Basewebform.cs

```
public class BaseWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
   private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
         string baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" +
                          Request.Url.Authority +
                          Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + 
                          "/";
          string jspath1 = baseUrl + "sweetalert/sweetalert2.min.css";
        string jspath2 = baseUrl + "sweetalert/sweetalert2.min.js";
        string jspath3 = baseUrl + "sweetalert/swalerthelper.js";  // this is my helper
        string jspath4 = baseUrl + "sweetalert/polyfill.min.js";  
        //register css
        HtmlLink styleLink = new HtmlLink();
        styleLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
        styleLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");                           
        styleLink.Href = jspath1;
        this.Page.Controls.Add(styleLink);

         //register sweetalert js  
         ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jscript2", jspath2);
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jscript3", jspath3);
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jscript4", jspath4); 
   }

  //swalerthelper.js 
  // it will overwrite the default browser alert() function.
   function alert(msg, msgtype) {
        msgtype = msgtype || 'warning';
        var tmp = msg.toLowerCase();
        if (tmp.indexOf('save')>0 || tmp.indexOf('success')>0){
           msgtype ='success';
    }  
        if (tmp.indexOf('error')>0 || tmp.indexOf('fail')>0){
           msgtype ='error';
    }  
        Swal({
            text: msg,
            type: msgtype,
            confirmButtonText: 'OK',
            confirmButtonColor: '#566573'

        })
 }
```

that it. have fun

Comment: sorry, forgot to said, all the webform, just inherit from the baseform will do. So all the inherited form will have the SweetAlert features,